Maximum number of vertices when dividing the $d$-dimensional simplex into $n$ convex polytopes.
The question is essentially in the title, but to be more precise: I would like to find the maximum number of vertices (i.e. distinct points of intersection) produced when splitting up the $d$-dimensional simplex into $n$ convex polytopes. (I make no assumptions about which, if either, of $n$ and $d$ is greater.) For example, it is easy to visualise that splitting a 2-dimensional simplex into 4 convex regions produces at most 9 vertices: the 3 original vertices plus 6 new vertices.
An easy upper bound of $n + d + 1 \choose d$ can be achieved by considering the maximal number of intersections of $n + d + 1$ hyperplanes in a $d$-dimensional space, but this is clearly quite loose. My intuition is that the number of vertices should be polynomial (rather than exponential) in $n$ and $d$.
My current best guess on how to show this is to argue that a maximal-vertex division can be produced by gradually splitting the simplex using $n-1$ hyperplanes, but clearly not all divisions into $n$ convex polytopes can be formed this way, and so the missing step is to argue that such other divisions can be ignored. I am also looking into results such as McMullen's Upper Bound Theorem in polyhedral combinatorics and the relevant generalisations of the Euler characteristic, but this is very much not my area of expertise and so any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Sadly, the number of vertices is exponential in $n$ and $d$. Here's an example with $n=2d+1$:
One of our convex sets is a small cube $C$ inside the simplex, and for each of its $2d$ facets, we have a convex set of the points outside of $C$ which are closer to that facet of the cube than any other.
Here's a sketch of this in the $d=2$ case:

This construction has $2^d$ vertices on the cube, plus some more at the boundaries of the simplex in various places.
